# Why is my app crashing?

Tags: java, android

I am making an android tic tac toe app. When I run the app on my **GS2**, the app crashes. I can't figure what the problem is, so here is my **onCreate()** method.(I havent added any more methods, my app is just starting..):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "coolvetica.ttf");
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button1.setTypeface(font);
    button2.setTypeface(font);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.startbuttonpressed);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resetbuttonpressed);
            // Perform action on click
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace ?

Comment: what is you ttf folder. in assets folder

Comment: I dont have a ttf folder, where should I have it?

Comment: please paste your log cat..

Comment: Read this: [public static Typeface createFromAsset (AssetManager mgr, String path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29)
You're trying to use these fonts *"coolvetica.ttf"* from your assets and looks like you don't actually have them there.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u9LztkHv logcat

Comment: I do have coolvetica.ttf inside my assets folder

Comment: we need the error logs that occur BEFORE the logs you've posted.

Comment: Step through it and see where it blows up.

Comment: It crashes when I set the typefaces of the buttons

Comment: This means either the buttons are null or the font is null. Either your font file is not in the assets directory, or R.id.button1 or R.id.Button01 do not exist in main.xml

Answer (score 0):

One of any number of things could be happening. Unless you post your logcat output it is impossible for anyone here to tell. The logcat you've posted isn't the error log.

One of two things is happening.

1. One of your ids is not actually in the xml layout you've inflated
2. You don't have the font in your "assets" directory

Comment: How do I get the logcat then?

Comment: In Eclipse -> Window -> Show View -> LogCat

Comment: in the logcat view, set it to verbose, and clear the logs, run the app, and then paste the output here

Comment: So, your error is on line 19 of your code. Make sure you actually have two Buttons with ids button1 and Button01 in your main.xml